# ScrollView not scrolling to the end in CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-cardview, cardview

I have a scrollview element with a CardView in it, and a bunch elements inside the LinearLayout.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/detailView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll02"
            android:layout_below="@id/ll01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="225dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="275dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailsTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="21dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

For some reason,  it seems unable to scroll all the way to the bottom, which cuts some of the text.

Screenshot:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `android:padding="10dp"` from `NestedScrollView` and add attribute `android:layout_margin="10dp"`

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `android:layout_margin="10dp"` from the CardView
2. Add `app:card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` to the CardView